# Highcharts line chart doesn't respect legend customization

Tags: highcharts

I would like to change the legend of my Highchart line chart to be a circle of a certain size. This works well if the chart type is 'area' but doesn't work at all if the chart type is 'line'.

This is how I want the legend to look: http://jsfiddle.net/gguwfyc8/3/

This is how it actually looks: http://jsfiddle.net/gguwfyc8/2/

It seems to ignore all the symbolXXX propertied of the legend.

```
legend: {
        symbolHeight:10,
        symbolRadius: 8,
        symbolWidth: 10
    }
```

How can I make my line chart legend to look like my area chart legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**JS FIDDLE**</kbd>

set the `fillOpacity 0`

Answer (score 0):

The 'symbolRadius' property is only applied when using a rectangle in the legend. if the chart type is 'line', the legend is not a rectangle.

Comment: Any way to make it a circle like in the area chart?

Comment: If you put the second comment as an answer I will mark it as the answer